# How to control the velocity of the spring back in Android OverScroller?

Tags: android, scroll, scrollview, android-scrollview, overscroll

I’m using the `OverScroller` class in Android to implement fling and spring back behavior in my app. I know that I can use the `fling` method with the `overY` parameter to specify the maximum number of pixels to overscroll by in the vertical direction. However, I’m not sure how to control the velocity of the **spring back** after a fling.

Is it possible to control the velocity of the spring back after a fling using the `OverScroller` class? If so, how can I do this? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Below is a sample of the springback animation I'm currently using. I find it to be slower than desired.

[image]

Comment: @Dev4Life I do not have code, i just play with simple sample I found on the web. As far as i know only this function is badly designed in OverScroller.java:

        private void startSpringback(int start, int end, int velocity) {
           ... 
           mDuration = (int) (1000.0 * Math.sqrt(-2.0 * delta / mDeceleration));
        }